# Fare for/cost of

Tags: word-usage

If I ask someone about the price of a "one-way trip ticket or a round trip ticket",  what's a natural way to ask that:

> What's the fare for **a one way/round trip** ticket?
>
> How much does a **one way/round trip** ticket cost?

And if I am asking a cab driver about a one way or round trip to a place:

> What's the fare for a **one way/round trip** to X?
>
> How much does a **one way/round trip** to X cost?

What do you think?

Comment: Many of your questions are easily answered by looking up these words in dictionaries. Please do so before asking them.

Comment: *How much is a (round trip / one way) ticket to X?*

Comment: But @JasonBassford can my sentences (in both the contexts)be used too?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish You asked what phrasing is natural. I commented on what *I* think the most natural phrasing is. There is nothing *ungrammatical* or even unnatural about your sentences. They just aren't what I would use. Also, if you're getting into a cab, you normally wouldn't mention *one way* or *round trip* at all. It would just be: *How much is it to X?*